# MS Excel - Search a value in entire column in sheet 1 and compare it with row value in sheet 1 and column value in sheet 2 and get True/False

Tags: excel

Need True or False values for Column Name in Sheet 2 based on Top Row values (Cust 1,Cust 2....) in Sheet 2 and corresponding column values in Sheet 1

Row 1 names in Sheet 2  have same values (Cust1..Cust 2 etc) as coulmn 2 in Sheet 1.

Sheet 1

```
Name Customer
A     Cust1
A     Cust2
B     Cust1
C     Cust2
```

Sheet 2

```
Name   Cust1  Cust2
A      True   True
B      True  False
C      False  True
```

I tried Index/match with array but not much use

Comment: What do you mean by 'row names'? Rows in excel don't have names. And where is your 'Sheet'?

Comment: First Row i will have Customer names...They are same values from Column 2 in sheet 2.Then i need to search these Customer names from sheet 2 column 2 corresponding to Column 1 in sheet and get True or false values.Need values in Sheet 1

Answer (score 0):

On sheet 2 in the top left TRUE/FALSE cell location, you could use the following formula and copy down and right as needed.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5)*(B$1=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image: POC]

Comment: Thanks for reply..I have edited my original post to avoid confusion.Need results in sheet 2 based on Sheet 1 values.

Comment: Thanks a lot,this is what i needed.One Flip side though this is very very slow for 25000 rows i have currently.In future plan to use a 500000 Row/900 Column data set.

Comment: Quickest way i found is use Pivot table and then use Index/Match to main table.